# Trying to pull, tag and push images using buildah in gitlab-ci pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, docker-image, buildah

I'm trying to write a script for a gitlab-ci pipeline to automate the process of pulling an image, tagging it and pushing it to my custom registry. I'm using buildah commands to do this and I keep getting errors. Can someone tell me how I need to fix this?
Thanks in advance :)

```
  script:
- |
  while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    if [[ ! $line =~ ^\s*(#|$) ]]; then
      elements=($line)
      if [ ${#elements[@]} -eq 4 ]; then
        registry="${elements[0]}/${elements[1]}"
        repository="${elements[2]}"
        tag="${elements[3]}"
      else
        registry=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
        repository=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
        tag=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}')
      fi
      echo "registry= $registry"
      echo "repository= $repository"
      echo "tag= $tag"
      echo "gcloud artifacts docker images list $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$repository --include-tags | grep $tag"
  
      if gcloud artifacts docker images list $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$repository --include-tags | grep $tag; then
        echo "Image $repository:$tag already exists in the repository. Skipping build and push.";
      else
        buildah pull "docker://$registry/$repository:$tag"
        
        # Tag the pulled image with the target repository and tag
        export IMAGE_ID=$(buildah images | grep '$repository' | grep '$tag' | awk '{print $3}')
        echo "image-id= $IMAGE_ID"
        buildah tag "$IMAGE_ID" "$DOCKER_REGISTRY/$repository:$tag"

        # Push the image to the Docker registry using Buildah
        buildah push "$DOCKER_REGISTRY/$repository:$tag"

        echo "Image $repository:$tag has been pushed to the artifact registry"
      fi
    fi
  done < images.txt
```